# Compare a row in two tables and only display columns with different value

Tags: mysql

If I have two similar tables in my DB where one table is like this:
TABLE One

```
ID   Name   Date       Profile  Status  Age    
213  John   12/2/2010   KDS      ONB    32
214  Robert 12/2/2011   KDS      ONB    22
```

and

TABLE TWO

```
ID   Name   Date       Profile  Status  Age    
213  John   12/2/2010   ABD      DNP    32
```

I want results like this

RESULT

```
ID   Profile  Status
213  ABD      DNP
```

So basically

1. Match only records that are in both tables based on primary key
2. Return ID (primary key) so I know what record it is
3. Return the updated values only from Table TWO

I am only able to display the 1st point using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_records AS one
INNER JOIN wp_records_update AS two ON one.ID = two.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want, but how about:

```
SELECT one.id, two.profile, two.status
FROM wp_records AS one
INNER JOIN wp_records_update AS two ON one.ID = two.ID
WHERE one.profile<>two.profile AND one.status<>two.status
```

I did not test it, but i think it should work

Comment: Thanks man .. but to be honest, there are over 80 columns that I have and really don't want to go map each column individually. Do you have any idea how can I do that for all columns? I just used profile & status column as in example.

Comment: You have to list each columns separately.

Comment: So, do you want to compare every column in the table or are there columns you want to skip?

Comment: I want to compare all columns and return only those whose values are different.

Answer (score -1):

I propose EXCEPT clause/operator

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

commenly  it  used  to combine  two  SELECT  statements  and  returns  rows  from the first SELECT statement that are not returned by the second SELECT statement

Comment: not relevant to the question at all. I don't want to get rows returned .. please read again.